# Can we keep GeoTiff in Azure File storage and Refer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I would like to store files in Azure File storage and connect from GeoServer. Is this feature available in GeoServer or any custom suggested way.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount an Azure File Storage as a network drive on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux?tabs=smb311) and than point to the GeoTiff or to a folder in case of a MosaicStorage.

Comment: we tried and it is working. Is there any way to try with Azure Blob Storage. Tried S3 https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html)But not finding any alternative for Azure blob storage. Do we have something for Azure blob storage?

Comment: There is a plugin where you can store the GWC cache in an Azure Blob https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/gwc-azure-blob/index.html. But I am not aware of using Blobs for the source GeoTiffs